# Storing a time stamp(Calendar object) with objectify

Tags: time, objectify

When i try to save an entity that contains with a Calendar object i get the following error.

> 'class java.util.GregorianCalendar' is not a registered @Subclass"

I want to be able to store a time stamp with my entity. Storing the time as a string works but id like to keep it as an object if possible.

Is there something specific i need to do to be able to store a Calendar object with objectify?

If i can not store a Calendar object, what is the best alternative for storing a timestamp with objectify(hopefully using standard java classes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is a good choice.

Comment: Date works. Do you know the particular reason date would work with objectify and calendar would not?

Comment: Looks like Date is [supported nativly](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types) by the datastore, while Calendar is not.  Why does Google support Date and not Calendar?  I don't know.  :)

Comment: java.util.Calendar is a horrowshow of API design. At least java.util.Date is simple. If you want something fancier, use joda time (Objectify has a translator for it).